# concept of composite primary key in Adventure Work Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I wonder to know why EmailAddress Table in Adventure work database uses composite primary key(BusinessEntityID,EmailAddressID(Identity))?
if it's something related to set cluster index for both fields, I would appreciate if tell me how composite primary key physically store(in which order and how data insert)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because this way, the same e-mail address can be used by multiple Persons as well as the same Person can use multiple e-mail addresses, i.e., it makes the relationship between person and e-mail address many-to-many.

If the need was merely to enforce that the e-mail address should belong to a person, it would have been enough to make it a foreign key and the column `BusinessEntityID` not nullable.

**Update:**

There are 2 tables involved here, `Person` and `EmailAddress`.

Each record in `Person` is identified by a `BusinessEntityID`. To associate a record from `Person` with a record in another table `T`, it is enough to include a column in this table `T` that refers to `BusinessEntityID`. Now, if we needed to ensure that all records in `T` *must* be associated with some record in `Person`, then we would place a foreign key constraint on `T.BusinessEntityID` and make it not nullable. If on top of this, we wanted to ensure that each record in `T` must be associated with one and only one record in `Person`, then we could place a uniqueness constraint on the column `T.BusinessEntityID`.

When we make 2 columns, `A` and `B` part of the primary key of a table, we are telling the database that the values of these two columns **together** must be unique for all records in that table. It has no bearing on the values in each of those columns and any foreign key relationships.

To illustrate:

```
Person (BusinessEntityID, Name) and PK is BusinessEntityID
---------------
1 | John
---------------
2 | Jane
---------------
3 | Sales Team



EmailAddress (BusinessEntityID, EmailAddressID, EmailAddress) and PK is [Business EntityID, EmailAddressID] where EmailAddress is auto-incremented
--------------
1 | 1 | john@example.com
------------------------
1 | 2 | john@contoso.com
------------------------
2 | 3 | jane@example.com
------------------------
2 | 4 | jane@contoso.com
------------------------
1 | 5 | sales@example.com
------------------------
2 | 6 | sales@example.com
------------------------
3 | 7 | sales@example.com
```

Data similar to the above is possible to put in the tables in your example. Now what is happening here?

There are 3 entities, John, Jane and Sales Team.

John has 2 personal e-mail addresses. Jane also has 2 personal e-mail addresses. In addition, the e-mail `address sales@example.com` belongs to the Sales Team but also to John and Jane.

This is a many-to-many relationship.

Additonally, if the composite key in EmailAddress is clustered, the keys are stored in the order in which they appear. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389348/should-a-composite-primary-key-be-clustered-in-sql-server) for more information.

Comment: thanks for you reply but if we didn't use BusinessEntityID as a primary key(just we have had EmailAddressID) I think still we could have same address for multiple person and vice versa. am i right?

Comment: is it correct that we think, related two fields in a table as a many to many relationship? because if BusinessEntityID in EmailAddress wasn't primary key(was just a FK), we still would have many mail for one person and many person for a same mail.

Comment: In fact you are absolutely correct about that. I actually cannot think of a good reason why they have constructed the `EmailAddress` table's PK this way. Usually If you have two tables `A` with `A.Id` and `B` with `B.Id`, and you want a many-to-many relationship between `A` and `B`, you make a third table `C` with `C.AId` and `C.BId` and you can make `(AId, BId) the PK for `C` and also set up FKs for `AId` and `BId` to enforce referential integrity. That's clearly not what's going on here. My aplogies for misguiding you in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of composition, one email address could not exist without a person.
So BusinessEntityID is also primary key for EmailAddress table

Comment: Thanks for your reply, would you please tell me or give me some references that how composite primary keys physically store. is just one of the fields consider as a cluster or both of them?

Comment: -1 for giving an incorrect reason for composite key setup and confusing it with a foreign key constraint.